# Can Agresti-Coull binomial confidence intervals be negative?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

According to http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc241.htm
Agresti-Coull intervals cannot be negative; however using the formula from Wikipedia as well as the binom.confint function in R with x = 0 and n = 5 produces an interval of (-0.05457239, 0.4890549).

Are there conflicting definitions of Agresti-Coull?

Edit -

Using binom.confint:

```
binom.confint(0, 5, .95, 'agresti-coull')
         method x n mean       lower     upper
1 agresti-coull 0 5    0 -0.05457239 0.4890549
```

Manually calculating the lower bound (using the formula from Wikipedia):

```
> n <- 5
> x <- 0
> n2 <- n+qnorm(0.025)^2
> p <- 1/n2 * (0 + .5 * zn^2) 
> zn <- qnorm(0.025)
1/n2 * (0 + .5 * zn^2) + zn * sqrt(1/n2 * p * (1 - p))
[1] -0.05457239
```

Comment: Although the Wikipedia article and the NIST page both reference the same paper, and give this confidence interval the same name, *they use different formulas.*  The NIST is correct that its formula will not produce negative values, but the Wikipedia formula can be negative. The NIST interval is attributed by Agresti & Coull to Wilson (1927); they call it the "score" interval. They proceed to develop an approximation for the score interval: the Wikipedia formula appears to be this approximation.

Comment: +1. The Agresti-Coull interval is symmetric about the point estimate and thus will certainly yield negative lower limit when you have 0 successes. It is not guaranteed identical to the Wilson interval.

Comment: It seems worth remarking that Agresti & Coull ended up recommending a rather simple approximation: add two to $x$ and four to $n$ to estimate $p$ and then compute the (simple) Wald interval $\hat{p}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/n}$.  This "confidence interval behaves adequately for practical application for essentially any $n$ regardless of the value of $p$" [p. 124]. Bear in mind, though, that this approximation assumes $\alpha\approx 0.05$; for extreme values of $\alpha$, the Wilson (score) interval is preferable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The lower limit of the formula from your link cannot be negative. But the interval from your link is *not* the Agresti-Coull interval, it is the *Wilson interval.*** The formulas from your link are for the so called **Wilson interval** and *not* the Agresti-Coull interval. [Agresti and Coull](https://www.stat.ufl.edu/%7Eaa/articles/agresti_coull_1998.pdf) list the formulas from your link in their paper and call it the *score confidence interval* (page 120). In the superb paper from Brown et al. (2001) [Interval estimation for a binomial proportion](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1009213286), it is called the Wilson interval. It is more commonly know as Wilson interval. They show in their article that the Wilson interval performs well even with small *n*. In the output of `binom.confint` the Wilson interval is denoted as `wilson` and can be calculated by setting the method `methods="wilson"` in `binom.confint`. Here is the `R` code for the (modified) Wilson confidence interval:

```
n <- 5
x <- 0

alpha <- 0.05

p.hat <- x/n

upper.lim <- (p.hat + (qnorm(1-(alpha/2))^2/(2*n)) + qnorm(1-(alpha/2)) * sqrt(((p.hat*(1-p.hat))/n) + (qnorm(1-(alpha/2))^2/(4*n^2))))/(1 + (qnorm(1-(alpha/2))^2/(n)))

lower.lim <- (p.hat + (qnorm(alpha/2)^2/(2*n)) + qnorm(alpha/2) * sqrt(((p.hat*(1-p.hat))/n) + (qnorm(alpha/2)^2/(4*n^2))))/(1 + (qnorm(alpha/2)^2/(n)))

#==============================================================================
# Modification for probabilities close to boundaries
#==============================================================================

if ((n <= 50 & x %in% c(1, 2)) | (n >= 51 & n <= 100 & x %in% c(1:3))) {
  lower.lim <- 0.5 * qchisq(alpha, 2 * x)/n
}

if ((n <= 50 & x %in% c(n - 1, n - 2)) | (n >= 51 & n <= 100 & x %in% c(n - (1:3)))) {
  upper.lim <- 1 - 0.5 * qchisq(alpha, 2 * (n - x))/n
}

upper.lim
[1] 0.4344825

lower.lim
[1] 3.139253e-17
```

Here, the lower limit is clearly 0 (the remaining is a numerical error). The Wilson interval in the output of `binom.confint` can be calculated by setting the option `methods="wilson"` and this is the same as the one we've calculated above:

```
library(binom)

binom.confint(x=0, n=5, methods="wilson")

  method x n mean        lower     upper
1 wilson 0 5    0 3.139253e-17 0.4344825
```

The function `binom.confint` implements the formulas given on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Agresti-Coull_Interval) for the Agresti-Coull interval:

```
n.hat <- n + qnorm(1-(alpha/2))^2

p.hat <- (1/n.hat) * (x + (1/2)*qnorm(1-(alpha/2))^2)

upper.lim2 <- p.hat + qnorm(1-(alpha/2))*sqrt((1/n.hat)*p.hat*(1-p.hat))

lower.lim2 <- p.hat - qnorm(1-(alpha/2))*sqrt((1/n.hat)*p.hat*(1-p.hat))

upper.lim2
[1] 0.4890549

lower.lim2
[1] -0.05457239
```

They are the same as the ones by `binom.confint` with the option `methods="ac"`:

```
library(binom)

binom.confint(x=0, n=5, methods="ac")

         method x n mean       lower     upper
1 agresti-coull 0 5    0 -0.05457239 0.4890549
```

Comment: When I tried binom.confint(0, 5, .95) I got a negative LL. Something is wrong.

Comment: @PeterFlom `binom.confint` doesn't use the formulas that the OP linked. The function uses those the formulas given on the Wiki page an those clearly can be negative. So there's nothing wrong with the function, it just uses a different formula.

Comment: thanks, seems silly to compute such approximations this day in age...

Comment: Not so; it's a surprisingly difficult problem and smart people have proposed different solutions from different views of what is most important. Computation is a secondary issue. No one obliges users to ask for two-sided confidence intervals here. All the methods proposed try to use defensible logic for different intervals. See Brown, L. D., T. T. Cai, and A. DasGupta. 2001. Interval estimation for a binomial proportion. Statistical Science 16: 101–133 for a superb review.

Comment: I'm okay with there being multiple solutions to binomial confidence intervals, but choosing between an approximation to the Agresti-Coull interval estimator and the actual Agresti-Coull interval estimator shouldn't be that controversial.

I can understand using the approximation when working with analytical expressions, but for a function that computes the interval on data, why would anyone ever bother with the approximation?

Comment: I see your point. As I recall, the Agresti-Coull method was explicitly promoted as something easy to teach and to calculate. The approximation was justified as mostly almost as good as more accurate approximations but simpler. From 1998 to 2013 a lot has changed. When every student has a laptop, it does now seem a little quaint. I tend to use the Jeffreys method, don't know the formula, but know where to look it up. Knowing how to do it by hand doesn't seem important.